# Import data from XML file with Drupal8

Tags: xml, drupal, import, drupal-8

I was wondering is there is a module in drupal8 for importing data from xml file,
And if there is one how does it work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)  is there but its not yet ready for d8.

Refer this link it may helps.

https://www.webomelette.com/xml-to-php-drupal

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look to three modules (combined actions) :
[migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate)

[migrate_plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus)

[migrate_source_xml](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_xml)

Also you have a development version module [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) , 
and finally you can find some help here

https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2016/05/04/using-the-new-drupal-8-migration-api-module.html

and here

https://www.palantir.net/blog/migrating-xml-drupal-8

Comment: Checking on the above referred Migrate source plugin - XML module, it says you should now use Migrate Plus for importing XML. Quoting: "This module has been superseded by the xml parser plugin in the Migrate Plus module (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus)".

Answer (score 0):

The [Feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)    will do the job, importing or aggregating data into nodes, users, taxonomy terms and other content entities using a web interface without coding a migration. Data can be imported from various formats, such as CSV, JSON, XML and RSS feeds.

Today latest  8.x-3.0-alpha8+ is Drupal 9 compatible also